# Loop through one specific column field to get a value in a multiple row set where a another Column field has equals something

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I need to get all the `GroupID` where `NetworkID` is equal to 5555

```
ID   Networking_Channel   Client_Groups   Client
1       5555                 1234         Client1
2       5555                 4321         Client2
```

My stored procedure looks like this. Do I need to use a `SqlDataReader` in C# to read all the values in the `GroupID` column?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spLoadClients
    @NetworkingChannel nvarchar(50) 
AS
    SELECT       
        Client_Groups
    FROM
        ClientTable
    WHERE        
        Networking_Channel = (@NetworkingChannel)

    RETURN
```

Code to execute is not working the reader is not getting any present values neither it says, Specified cast is not valid. If you look at the stored procedure above I want to select the specified Column and get all values in all rows of that column where `NetworkID = 5555` that way I can get a groups of different `ClientID` that share the same `NetworkID 5555`.

PLEASE HELP! thank you

```
 SqlDataReader reader;
 string LoadClients = "spLoadClients";

 using (SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
 using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(LoadClients, sqlConnectionCmdString))
 {
     sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@NetworkingChannel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = IntializedNetworks[i].ToString();

     sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();

     using (reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              IntializedPostNet[i] = reader.GetSqlInt32(i).ToString();
          }

          reader.Close();
     }

     sqlConnectionCmdString.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I made the table sample above show the fields that correspond with the stored procedure field requests.

Comment: Did you try to use the `SELECT` query directly without creating a stored procedure in your `UpdateCommand` string?
If that works, you could try to remove the `RETURN` from your stored procedure. I don't know how returning results from stored procedures works exactly in sql server, but here's some info: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_return_result_set.html

Comment: Yes I created a Stored procedure, I can get data from the table, the query executes, the problem is the reader is not retrieving all the data from the column according to the readers index so I can put that data in array. I mean the code should speak for it self in what I am trying to achieve. MyArray[I] = reader.Index[I].value something similar to that, I just need to know how to access the index method through a loop or some process that works

Comment: `reader.GetSqlInt32(i)` accesses _column_, not _row_. Reader gets __one__ row at a time. You read data from column, and then get another row. So index of column never changes. On the other side, you want to store the value to array but you don't change the index inside `while` loop. In my opinion you should not use array in situations where you do not know number of items in advance (that is, before you instantiate the array). You should use `List<string>` and `.Add()` items to it: `while (reader.Read()) { IntializedPostNet.Add(reader.GetSqlInt32(0).ToString()); }`. Note zero column index.

Comment: Thank you It works now I got I used the foreach method